Unit Test Case Error: No AppConfigProvider found in context
I'm trying to test a function in Dart that involves accessing configuration data from the context. The function call looks like this: context.typographyConstants. However, typographyConstants seems to be part of an extension function, and the actual call involves accessing configuration through AppConfigProvider.of(this).config.typographyConstants. How can I properly mock this for testing purposes?
when(() => uikit.AppConfigProvider.of(context).config.typographyConstants)
.thenReturn(MockTypographyConstants());
